# Sonar qube in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

How can I make that sonar qube server analyze a mvn project on jenkins?. I have a pipeline project from CSM with a jenkinfile which point to a groovy file where all steps of the job are executed. All steps are working ok (mvn test, mvn package, mvn compile, etc), but don´t know how to execute the mvn sonar:sonar. It gives following error.Image show how do I have sonar configured in jenkins and the job step where it fails.

And this is how I have the step described in groovy file of pipeline:

```
stage ('SonarQube analysis') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('https://sonarqube.xxxxx.com') {
        sh 'mvn sonar:sonar'
    }  
}
```

[image: Jenkins logs]

Answer (score 3):

Try using the server installation name in withSonarQubeEnv, right now you are using URL i.e. `withSonarQubeEnv('Grey Azure Sonarqube')`.

[Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/#code-withsonarqubeenv-code-prepare-sonarqube-scanner-environment)